# Remove duplicates from Array using BitSet?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to understand the implementation of below statement found on stackoverflow

> Can use BitSet, as you walk the array of values, set the corresponding bit to true. Then you can walk over the bit set and output the corresponding value whenever you find a bit set to true

I know very simple way of removing duplicates from `array` of `int`. But struggling to understand how it can be implemented using above statement found on this site.

ref link

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667543/remove-duplicates-from-a-large-integer-array-using-java
```

can anyone suggest how it can be implemented ?

Comment: What if instead you used an array of `boolean`?

Comment: @ScottHunter, how it help to remove duplicates ?

Comment: The BitSet is a set, meaning each value is only present once. The first pass adds all values in the array (which must contain integers) to the set. Then the BitSet is used instead of the array in pass two. The BitSet contains the unique values from the array. If the goal is another array you would need to create one and copy the values back from the BitSet. Note that the linked article has a limitation on the integer values; if your integers can take any value it may not work as well for you. I don't think BitSet is sparse, so it may have to allocate bits all the way up to your largest value.

Comment: You could use any kind of Set; BitSet is a particular implementation which, as @ewramner points out, imposes certain limitations.

Comment: @ScottHunter to be clear, `BitSet` doesn't implement `Set`, but it can be thought of as having set-like semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet();
// walk the array of values
for (int i : array) {
  // set the corresponding bit to true
  bs.set(i);
}

// walk over the bit set
for (int i = 0; i < bs.size(); ++i) {
  // output the corresponding value whenever you find a bit set to true
  if (bs.get(i)) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

As noted by [ewramner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70685852/remove-duplicates-from-array-using-bitset/70686036#comment124960645_70685852), `BitSet` is not sparse, so this will allocate enough bits for everything up to the largest value in the array. If there are very few values in the array, or they are all a lot larger than zero, this will probably be quite inefficient, and putting things in a `Set` (e.g. a `HashSet` or `TreeSet`) would be a better option.

---

This is a more efficient way to walk over the bitset looking for true values:

```
for (int i = -1; (i = bs.nextSetBit(i + 1)) != -1;) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```